# How to get the status of property in the RTL

Tags: simulation, register-transfer-level, system-verilog-assertions

In some scenarios, injecting error will trigger the assert to be fail. so , I pass the switch to turn off this assert by $testplusargs. Is there a way to get the status of property(vacuous true, real true or fail) at the end of test cases, for example by PLI or other ways supplied by simulator(I am using vcs). Anyone has some idea for this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can register some VPI callbacks to the assertion and check the number of failed/passed counts.
You could also in system verilog count number of pass/fail of the property with the action blocks.

For example : 
   assert property(p_test) begin
   pass_cnt++;
   end else begin
   fail_cnt++
   end